# Which allocator is used when allocating a nested STL container?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, vector, allocator

I have a question about STL classes and allocators that doesn't seem to be easy to find online. Does anyone know which allocator is used in a nested STL class? For example:

```
typedef std::vector<int> myvect;
```

//the line below was edited as pointed out by subsequent replies/comments

```
typedef std::map<int, myvect, std::less<int>, A> mymap; //uses my custom allocator for map creation
```

Let's call the default allocator `D`, and assume I have a custom allocator `A`.

What would happen if I did the following:

- Create a map:

  ```
  mymap mapInstance;
  ```
- Now, assuming an entry exists for `mapInstance[0]`, suppose I push a value into the vector:

  ```
  mapInstance[0].push_back(999);
  ```

What allocator is used for the dynamic memory of the vector `mapInstance[0]`?

My understanding so far is that the default allocator `D` is used, but I want to confirm that the custom allocator `A`, which was passed to the map, is not instead used. (As far as I know, this would only happen were I to use some sort of nested allocation option.)

I understand, of course, that the metadata/header info for `mapInstance[0]` is allocated using the custom allocator `A`. What I'm concerned about is the *dynamic* memory part, that is, the part after `d_dataBegin`.

Comment: The first thing you should know is that in the standard library, the allocator changes the type of the container (it is a template parameter of the container), and the default allocator is stateless so the *exact* copy of the allocator that is used in your example will not make a difference.

Comment: what is `d_dataBegin`?!  that doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere until the last word of the question!

Answer (score 11):

Your question is related to the [Scoped Allocator Model](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2554.pdf), which is a style of allocator design that automatically propagates a container's allocator to the container's elements, so that you can ensure all a container's elements are allocated from the same allocator. More on that below.

To answer your question:

1) Containers do not use the scoped allocator model by default, you have to request it explicitly (see `scoped_allocator_adaptor` below)

2) Your nested container is type `std::vector<int>` which means it uses the default `std::allocator<int>` allocator, and all instances of that type are equal, so the answer to your question is that it uses the standard allocator - it doesn't matter which one, because every `std::allocator<int>` is the same.

---

**The rest of this answer is just a thought experiment, the answer to your question is above: `vector<int>` *always* uses `std::allocator<int>`**

Now, if your nested type was `std::vector<int, A1<int>>` where `A1<int>` is a custom allocator the question gets more interesting.

The nested container will use the allocator it's constructed with, and you haven't shown that because you've said "*assuming an entry exists for `mapInstance[0]`*" and how that entry is created is what determines what allocator it will use.

If that entry is created like this:

```
mapInstance[0];
```

then the entry is default-constructed and will use a default-constructed `A1<int>`.

If that entry is created like this:

```
A1<int> a1( /* args */ );
myvect v(a1)
mapInstance.insert(mymap::value_type(0, v));
```

then the entry will be a copy of `v` and in C++03 its allocator will be a copy of `v.get_allocator()`, but in C++11 its allocator will be a copy of `std::allocator_traits<A1<int>>::select_on_container_copy_construction(v.get_allocator())`, which *might* be a copy of `v.get_allocator()` but might be something different (e.g. a default-constructed `A1`.)

(In C++03 the entry's allocator cannot be changed after it's created, so the answer would end here, but in C++11 it can be replaced. I assume we're talking C++11 for the rest of this question, because allocators are not very interesting in C++03.)

If that entry is modified like this:

```
A1<int> a1( /* args */ );
myvect v(a1)
mapInstance[0] = v;
```

then the vector gets copy-assigned to, which *might* replace the allocator, depending on the value of `std::allocator_traits<A1<int>>::propagate_on_container_copy_assignment::value`

If that entry is modified like this:

```
A1<int> a1( /* args */ );
mapInstance[0] = myvect(a1);
```

then the vector gets move-assigned to, which *might* replace the allocator, depending on the value of `std::allocator_traits<A1<int>>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value`

If that entry is modified like this:

```
A1<int> a1( /* args */ );
myvect v(a1)
swap( mapInstance[0], v );
```

then the vector gets swapped, which *might* replace the allocator, depending on the value of `std::allocator_traits<A1<int>>::propagate_on_container_swap::value`

---

Now, if `A` is `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<A1<std::pair<const int, myvect>>>` things get even more interesting!  The `scoped_allocator_adaptor` is, as its name suggests, an adaptor, which allows any allocator type to be used with the *Scoped Allocator Model* which means that a container's allocator can be passed to the container's children, and to its children's children, etc. (as long as those types use allocators and can be constructed with them.)

**By default containers and allocators do *not* use the scoped allocator model** you need to use `scoped_allocator_adaptor` (or write your own allocator type that works the same) to use it.  (And C++03 has no support at all for scoped allocators.)

If that entry is created like this:

```
mapInstance[0];
```

then instead of the entry being default-constructed the `scoped_allocator_adaptor` will construct it with a copy of the map's allocator, so the entry will be constructed like `myvect( A1<int>(mapInstance.get_allocator()) )`.

If that entry is created like this:

```
A1<int> a1( /* args */ );
myvect v(a1)
mapInstance.insert(mymap::value_type(0, v));
```

then the entry will have a copy of `v`'s data, but will not use its allocator, instead it will be passed an allocator by the `scoped_allocator_adaptor`, so will be constructed like: `myvect( v, A1<int>(mapInstance.get_allocator()) )`.

---

If that's all a bit confusing, welcome to my world, but don't worry, in your case `vector<int>` will *always* use `std::allocator<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

The default allocator `D` is used for the `push_back` call.

In fact, the default allocator is used for the `map` as well, because the *type* of the container specifies to use the default allocator. Assuming your `A` inherits from `std::allocator`, all that's happening is that your allocator gets sliced to the default one and the container behaves just like you didn't pass an allocator instance at all.

Comment: I didn't quite get that Mark-- I edited my original question to pass the allocator correctly to the map, but I don't get the part where you talk about A getting sliced to the default one and the container behaving like I didn't pass an allocator instance at all.
Let's say that the allocator A has some special memory debugging built into it.  If I use it to create A as per my edit in the original question, would what you say apply (and just D be used?... I don't quite agree with that, or I'm missing something).
About D used for the push_back call, I agree.  Thanks!

Comment: For other readers' benefit, when this answer was written the question  used `std::map<int, myvect> mapInstance(A)` so Mark B is right that that map used the default allocator -- the question has been edited so this answer looks wrong now though.